# gulp-image-resize With Multiple Images

Tags: gulp, image-resizing, gulp-imagemin

Is it possible to have [gulp-image-resize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-image-resize) spit out multiple images, for example a @1x and @2x image. My gulp task looks like this currently:

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('test.jpg')
    .pipe(imageResize({ width: 1920 }))
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '@2x'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/img'))
    .pipe(imageResize({ width: 960 }))
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/img'))
});
```

But it just places an image called `test@2x.jpg` with a width of 960px into my destination directory.

Is there a way to have two images saved. One called `test.jpg` with a width of 960px, and one called `test@2x.jpg` with a width of 1920px?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are renaming the file too early, just put the rename pipe after the first gulp.dest.

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('test.jpg')
    .pipe(imageResize({ width: 1920 }))
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/img')) // move this line to before the gulp.dest
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '@2x'
    }))
    .pipe(imageResize({ width: 960 }))
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/img'))
});
```